# Wacom Finger touch not working after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen, wacom

On my Thinkpad X230 Tablet after the upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 the finger touch stopped working.

It is listed by xsetwacom:

```
xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus           id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch         id: 11  type: TOUCH     
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser           id: 16  type: ERASER
```

But touching the screen neither moves the cursor nor triggers a mouse click. And the wacom control panel does not list the finger touch, only stylus and eraser.

Any idea?

Comment: Got similar problem. Can't even install wacom bamboo pad on 14.04 version. Does anybody know some working (!) guide how to fix it?